# Python: How to return a result from a conditional and then have it re-enter the conditional statement

Tags: python, if-statement

Thanks ahead of time for the help. I having problems with my if else statement. Below is my code. Basically, if the `else:`is entered it means there is no data and the rest of my code should not run. What I need to do is when the `else:`is entered I need it to return new randx and randy values which will then be entered back into the `if (dem_arr[randx, randy] > -100):`. I have tried using while with no success.

```
neighbors = [(-1,-1), (-1,0), (-1,1), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0), (1,-1), (0,-1)]
mask = np.zeros_like(dem_arr, dtype = bool)
stack = [(randx, randy)] # push start coordinate on stack
counterStack = [(randx, randy)]

if (dem_arr[randx, randy] > -100):
    count = 0
    while count <= 121:
        x, y = stack.pop()
        mask[x, y] = True
        for dx, dy in neighbors:
            nx, ny = x + dx, y + dy
            if (0 <= nx < dem_arr.shape[0] and 0 <= ny < dem_arr.shape[1] and dem_arr[x, y] > -100 and dem_arr[nx, ny] > -100 and not mask[nx, ny] and abs(dem_arr[nx, ny] - dem_arr[x, y]) <= 5):    #set elevation differnce
                stack.append((nx, ny))  #if point is selected (true) array position gets added to stack and process runs over again
                if ((nx, ny) not in counterStack):
                    counterStack.append((nx, ny)) 
                    dem_copy[(nx, ny)] = 8888
                    dem_copy[randx, randy] = 8888
                    count += 1
else:   #if enters else then need new randx and new randy points need to be returned and re-enter the above if(dem_arr...)
    print 'Point chosen has no data'
    randx = random.randint(0, row-1)
    randy = random.randint(0, col-1)
```

Thanks for the help.

-R

Comment: You can do it by using `while`, `break` and `continue`.

Comment: I have not been able to properly structure the while, break, continue statements. Could you provide an example or tell me where in my code I need to enter these statements? Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code like this.

before:

```
if (dem_arr[randx, randy] > -100):
    ...
else:
    ...
```

after:

```
while(True):
    if (dem_arr[randx, randy] > -100):
        ...
        break#break from this while-loop.
    else:
        ...
        continue#go back and continue this while-loop.
```